# Jaspersoft visualise.js report export failing to produce file

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I hope there is few among you who have experience with Jaspersoft Reports and their new visualise.js api

I have a problem with visualise.js not producing report export file. What happens is:

1. I am able to succsefully load the report through the visualise.js API, it loads and displays on my web page
2. Export controls load up successfully too, so I have dropdown with export file formats and a button to export the file.
3. **When I click the export button though, the whole page reloads as if the export button was really a submit button and nothing happens.**
4. **Occasionally, the export will work and it will produce file. Though there is no pattern to when it will produce the file and when it will fail.**

Below is the code I am using for this (I am using plain text auth for testing purposes):

```
    visualize({
    auth: {
        name: "mylogin",
        password: "mypass",
        organization: "organization_1"
        }

}, function (v) {

        var $select = buildControl("Export to: ", v.report.exportFormats),
            $button = $("#button"),
            report = v.report({
                resource: "/FPSReports/journal",
                container: "#export",
                params: {
                    "journal_ref": [ "<?php echo $reference; ?>" ],
                },

                success: function () {
                    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
                },

                error : function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

        $button.click(function () {

            console.log($select.val());

            report.export({
                // export options here
                outputFormat: $select.val(),
                // exports all pages if not specified
                // pages: "1-2"

            }, function (link) {
                var url = link.href ? link.href : link;
                window.location.href = url;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });

        function buildControl(name, options){

            function buildOptions(options) {
                var template = "<option>{value}</option>";
                return options.reduce(function (memo, option) {
                    return memo + template.replace("{value}", option);
                }, "")
            }

            var template = "<label>{label}</label><select>{options}</select><br />",
                content = template.replace("{label}", name)
                    .replace("{options}", buildOptions(options));

            var $control = $(content);
            $control.insertBefore($("#button"));
            //return select
            return $($control[1]);      
        }       

});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-8"></div>
      <div class="grid-8 center"><a href="" id="button" class="large link_button margin2">Export</a></div>
      <div class="grid-8"></div>

    </div>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-24" id="export"></div>
</div>
```

The only parameter comes from URI segment (I am using codeigniter framework):

```
$reference = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer that seems to work, and has resolved the issue. Posting it here in case anyone else has this specific problem like I did.

**In brief:**
After spending hours looking at console debug output I have realised that each time I tried to send a request for export a new session would be opened. Without logging out of the previous one. And apparently that is a no-no. I do not know JS very well but from what I understood there was session id mismatch in request. Please feel free to correct me here :)

**The solution to this problem (or for example if you are having authentication issues with visualize.js) is very simple. Set the authentication in global config:**

```
visualize.config({
auth: {
    name: "superuser",
    password: "superuser"
}
});
```

No matter if you are using tokens or plain text or whatever else auth is available through the api.

Then do your stuff wherever else on your website:

```
visualize(function (v) {
v("#container1").report({
    resource: "/public/Samples/Reports/06g.ProfitDetailReport",
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
});
 });

 visualize(function (v) {
   v("#container2").report({
    resource: "/public/Samples/Reports/State_Performance",
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.message);
         }
    });
    });
```

Everything should work for you as it did for me. This works in version 5.6 and 6.1 of visualize.js.

**Further reading and links from my research:**

[Token based authentication to Jasper reports failing when used with visualize.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331596/token-based-authentication-to-jasper-reports-failing-when-used-with-visualize-js)

[Visualize.js authentication error after second login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519192/visualize-js-authentication-error-after-second-login)

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/842695/visualizejs-authentication-error

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/845886/authentication-error-refresh-credentials-visualizejs

**Code example (5.6):**
http://jsfiddle.net/TIBCO_JS_Community/sozzq0sL/embedded/

**Api samples (6.1):**
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/visualizejs-api-samples-v61

**Api samples (5.6):**
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/visualizejs-api-notes-and-samples-v56

Really hope this will help someone new to Jaspersoft & visualize.js like me.